# Oracle Replace String

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have data in a column like below.

```
ColumnA

APX-0150004-225 02A,APX-0150004-234 02A 

APX-0170009-001 04C,APX-0170021-002 04C,APX-0170021-004 02R

APX-0170012-001 04C,APX-0170012-002 02R,APX-0170021-003 04C,APX-0170021-005 01R
```

And I want to **replace every three characters before comma with null** and output should be like below

```
ColumnA

APX-0150004-225 ,APX-0150004-234

APX-0170009-001 ,APX-0170021-002 ,APX-0170021-004

APX-0170012-001 ,APX-0170012-002 ,APX-0170021-003 ,APX-0170021-005
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ColumnA ) AS
SELECT 'APX-0150004-225 02A,APX-0150004-234 02A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'APX-0170009-001 04C,APX-0170021-002 04C,APX-0170021-004 02R' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'APX-0170012-001 04C,APX-0170012-002 02R,APX-0170021-003 04C,APX-0170021-005 01R' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( ColumnA, '[^,]{3}(,|$)', '\1' ) AS ColumnA
FROM   table_name
```

**Output**:

```
COLUMNA
------------------------------------------------------------------
APX-0150004-225 ,APX-0150004-234
APX-0170009-001 ,APX-0170021-002 ,APX-0170021-004
APX-0170012-001 ,APX-0170012-002 ,APX-0170021-003 ,APX-0170021-005
```

Comment: If row has data like APX-0150038-003 then regex_replace is replacing it to 
APX-0150038-

Comment: Since the sub-string you want to replace seems to have the format of two digits then an upper case alphabetical character then you could try `'\d{2}[A-Z](,|$)'` as the regular expression to replace.